# why does "Add User" on admin does not show all the fields in admin to add new user in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-registration, django-users

This is how my admin look now.
[image]

when I click the `Add User` on the right side, I get a `form` which does not have first name, Last name and Email address fields. but only `username and password`, as below
[image]

I am using `Django-registration` to register new users. I have attached `UserProfile` to `User`. The `UserProfile` has only two fields, `Photo` and `isPublic`?

how can I get my `admin` to include all fields (such as First name, last name, email address) in the `admin form`.

EDIT:
Traceback here

```
ValueError at /admin/auth/user/add/
too many values to unpack
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/add/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
too many values to unpack
Exception Location: /Users/Documents/virtualenvs/django/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py in flatten_fieldsets, line 90
Python Executable:  /Users/Documents/virtualenvs/django/django/bin/python
Python Version:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UserAdmin` of `django.contrib.auth` [specifically overrides the form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ffab9cee1a5bd1a2f6c326ae970d92526f9a304/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70) used for adding a new `User`. It differs from the change form because it needs to ask twice for the password.

If you [look at the source code for `UserAdmin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9ffab9cee1a5bd1a2f6c326ae970d92526f9a304/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L55), you'll see that you can set your own creation form by setting the `add_form` option. It should inherit from the original `UserCreationForm` to keep the password setting logic. For example:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')  # etc...

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + ("More fields", {"fields": ('first_name', 'last_name')},)

# don't forget to register your custom admin class
admin.site.unregister(UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: I get `too many values to unpack` in the add_fieldsets, but I cannot figure out why it comes?

Comment: It should work. Can you paste the traceback somewhere?

Comment: What is your value of `add_fieldsets`?